# Connect to remote sql server via alias

Tags: entity-framework, sql-server-2012

My connection string is working when I am connecting via IP adresss

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="Data Source=ALIAS_SERVERNAME;Initial Catalog=DATABASE_NAME;Integrated Security=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
    <add name="DefaultContainer" connectionString="metadata=res://*/Models.Db.ModelName.csdl|res://*/Models.Db.ModelName.ssdl|res://*/Models.Db.ModelDb.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=192.168.0.61;initial catalog=DATABASE_NAME;integrated security=True;multipleactiveresultsets=True;application name=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
```

I have created Alias on remote server, like I did it localy (same ports and names) ,but it doesnt working. And when I put IP addres in connection string, like the one I have posted it is working. 
Can someone pleas give me some instructions on how to troubleshot problem.

Error I am getting when I try to connect via Alias, and via IP it is working. Btw can connect localy via Alias.

> (EntityException): The underlying provider failed on Open.

Comment: Have anyone try to ask me did system admin gave same host names? @Murat Yıldız thanks for trying to help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, your DB server is aware of its alias name, but your application server is not. You have to create alias on application server. 
You can do that with

> cliconfg.exe

(Start > Run > cliconfg > Click "OK") 
And than set your protocol, and port same as on DB server

Answer (score 0):

You might need to add SQL Server name i.e. SQLEXPRESS, etc. at the end of your alias as shown below:

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="Data Source=ALIAS_SERVERNAME\SQLEXPRESS; 
        Initial Catalog=DATABASE_NAME;Integrated Security=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />    
</connectionStrings>
```

If you do not use default name for MSSQL Server then you need to change with what you used as name of it. You can check it on the Server Name field of the Connect dialog of SQL Server Management Studio as shown below.

[image]

**Update:** Here is the DataLink properties dialog shown below:

[image]

If it does not solved the problem, have a look at [The underlying provider failed on open](http://www.technologycrowds.com/2015/04/the-underlying-provider-failed-on-open.html). Hope this helps...

Comment: I am connecting from Managment Studio only with alias, without SQL instancce. So I dont think that is the issue.

Comment: And when I was createing alias name I have add sql server name as well, but still the same error..

Comment: Create a blank notepad and rename it to "X.UDL" Double click open it, under connections tab choose the server name/enter the name use the correct credentials and DB OK to save it. Now open the file in Notepad and check, compare the connection string properties with this...

Comment: I am sorry, but I dont get you "under connections tab choose the server name/enter the name use the correct credentials and DB" 
Where under connections tab?

Comment: I added a screenshot above.

Comment: OK, got it. And there is only host name without SQL instance name, but I have tried it with or without SQL instance name and it is not working.

Comment: But in some cases SQL Server name is required and one of my Colleague has experience with it in the last month. So, please have a look at my last update above. Hope this helps...

Comment: Yes, I have tried to do that, but it sows not resolve it.